# disable roslisp

Tags: ros, roslisp, armhf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to compile ros without roslisp?

SBCL is not available on armfh, and I'd really like to run ROS on this device. :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/80931/disable-roslisp/) by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1070 on 2013-09-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RodBelaFarin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3527/rodbelafarin/) on 2013-11-01**:
same problem here. was anybody able to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turns out the roslisp is not required, and even though the ros-desktop package fails to install you can still install pretty much everything you need on ARM.

---

Originally posted by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) with karma: 1070 on 2013-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dave.peacock](https://answers.ros.org/users/12111/dave.peacock/) on 2014-02-19**:
Any tips on how to do this? I have an armel processor running an old Debian, just trying to get ros-base 'variant' built, don't see any docs other than the basic install from source pages on the wiki. Thanks in advance

**Comment by [RodBelaFarin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3527/rodbelafarin/) on 2014-02-19**:
yes, go to your catkin workspace inside the source folder and delete sbcl and everything, which does not compile, from the source-folder manually. afterwards ROS Hydro worked for me very fine on my PandaBoard armhf.